# Does the Disciplined badge work on SuperUser?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

Yesterday I deleted an answer that had 4 upvotes to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/50680/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-what-app-is-using-most-of-my-bandwidth-in-windows) (the answer was a bit misleading and the OP told me it was incorrect), yet I've yet to see a badge.

There has never been a Disciplined badge awarded on SU, even though it's a bronze badge. Does the badge even work?

Answer (score 8):

Yep, looks like a bug. I went in and cleaned it up, and I also added the missing "Fanatic" badge.

Comment: Thanks! That was incredibly fast :)

Comment: Seems to be broken again. I deleted one of my answers that had 4 votes: http://superuser.com/questions/52790/recommended-free-codecs-to-play-dvd-in-windows-media-player-11/52800#52800. No badge.

Comment: you only get it once, as specified on the badge page itself. If the badge can be awarded multiple times, it will say so. If it does not, you cannot.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the mistake! Thanks for clearing that up!